# Displaying boundaries in a stacked barplot for every part

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Having a DataFrame like:

```
data= {"A":[10,9], "B":[4,3],"C":[0,4]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=data, index= ["Jan", "Feb"])
```

Which looks like:

```
        A   B   C   
   Jan  10  4   0   
   Feb  9   3   4
```

And i build a plot with stacked bars. (Picture at the end)

```
ax = df.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,figsize=(16,9))
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

Every column has a border value which should not be exceed.

```
borders = {"A": 8, "B":4, "C": 3}
```

Now i want to display the borders in the plot, but building a constant line for the whole graph is not sufficient. Every bar needs a own presentation of the borders.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `df` rows with `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()`, so you look at every single bar and trace three red-lines, one for each column.
The height of:

- the first red line depends solely on `'A'` border, so it has always the same height for each bar
- the second red line depends on actual `'A'` value plus `'B'` border, so it has variable height for each bar
- the third red line depends on actual `'A' + 'B'` value plus `'C'` border, so it has variable height for each bar

I use `k` counter to move among bars.

```
k = 0
for i, _ in df.iterrows():
    ax.plot([k - 0.25, k + 0.25], [borders['A'], borders['A']], 'r')
    ax.plot([k - 0.25, k + 0.25], [borders['B'] + df.loc[i, 'A'], borders['B'] + df.loc[i, 'A']], 'r')
    ax.plot([k - 0.25, k + 0.25], [borders['C'] + df.loc[i, 'A'] + df.loc[i, 'B'], borders['C'] + df.loc[i, 'A'] + df.loc[i, 'B']], 'r')
    k += 1
```

[image]